# How to detect Intel Xeon Phi coprocessor on Windows?

Tags: c, windows, msdn, pci-e, xeon-phi

Is there any C/C++ API's which I can use to detect whether the system has a xeon phi co-processor in it?

Comment: Use CPUID instruction. With `MOV EAX, 00H CPUID` instructions sequence for basic info. On return exam EAX, for a **Intel® Xeon Phi™ coprocessor**, it will contain **04H** for basic information query and **80000008H** for extended. Look for **CPUID** in the doc https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/forum/278102/327364001en.pdf.

Comment: @Frankie_C, Can it be used to find to find Xeon Phi PCIe chip, or just the standalone CPU?

Comment: Did you open the link I provided in my comment? It is the CPU instructions manual for the **Xeon Phi coprocessor**. The Xeon **is** an X86 processor multicore, the CPUID instruction give info about the chip where it is executed.